# Why is Percy Jackson said to be 'son of Zeus, Hades or Poseidon'?

Tags: plot-explanation, percy-jackson-sea-of-monsters

In *Percy Jackson: Sea of Monsters* from 2013 at the beginning it's clear that Percy Jackson is:

> Son of Poseidon, god of the sea.

Also the whole plot suggests that.

So why does the centaur at 25min of the movie say that he is:

> the only living half-blood heir of Zeus, Hades or Poseidon

The same at 1:35min:

> only living human child... of Poseidon, Hades or Zeus

Why are they using the "**or**" statement? Aren't they sure which son he is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They know very well whose son he is. What they mean with that statement is that apart from Percy Jackson there are no other children of *any* of those three gods. The reason they say it like this is that those three gods (or the human children thereof) have some specific importance to them, and **Percy is the only known child among all three** of those gods.

Comment: That's why it becomes a big deal later on when they find children of Hades.

Answer (score 2):

Zeus, Poseídon and Hades are the big three in Greek Mythology. Brothers, sons of the titan Chronos, (time), they form the royalty of the Greek Pantheon. Zeus, king of the Sky, Poseidon, king of the Oceans, and Hades, king of the underworld. The three most powerful Gods. Hence their offspring are considered the most powerful among the demigods. As we see, Percy is quite powerful, having his fathers control over water.

What the mean by those phrases is that it doesn't matter who his father is, as long as it's one of the Big Three.